# Getting all the strings between two strings in an array in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm looking for a way to grab all the strings between two strings in an array.

String[] list = inputOCR.split("(?=\p{Space})"); = this is the way I built the array.

The order of the strings goes like [Other,Name, Middle, First, Last,Address, word, word, word, word, word, word, License, etc, etc, etc, etc]
How do I get all the words between address and license inside the array?

Update: The index of the array isnt fixed based on the OCR scan,so I also have to look for the word "Address", and "License" in the array.

Comment: Did you try anything? Basic solution would be to loop through the array and extracting everything between the two words

Comment: I'm trying my best to learn, but I'm stuck at the moment as I don't fully understand the logic to loop through the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah yes, indexes can be confusing!  I've got some code that might help you along.  What you want to do, once you've split the words into an array, is find the index (position) of the words that are the start and end of your search.  In this case, "address" and "license".  Then you can loop between these values to get the words you need.

```
public class GetWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputOCR = "This contains some address random words used to test License should not be picked up";
        String[] list = inputOCR.split(" "); 

        int startPosition = getIndexOfWordInArray(list, "address") + 1;
        int endPosition = getIndexOfWordInArray(list, "license");

        for (int i = startPosition; i < endPosition; i++) {
            System.out.println(list[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int getIndexOfWordInArray(String[] list, String word) {
        int index = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i].equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }
}
```

The code above splits the string on spaces, then gets the positions of "address" and "license" from the index.  It then loops through the array, printing the words between those two positions.  The code adds 1 to the position of "address", because you want to exclude it and it stops just before the position of "license".

Instead of printing the words, you can add them to an ArrayList, which is an array that can grow dynamically, depending on how much you put into it.

I tried to keep the code as simple and beginner-friendly as possible, but please ask if it's still unclear.

Comment: I really like your answer considering he is a beginner!

Comment: Oh wow really appreciate it! You really made it as simple as possible for a beginner to understand the logic of the code. Such a big help!! Thank you!

Comment: I just have a question. In putting the extracted words to a textview, textView.append(list[i]) correct? Or I have to assign it to a string before setText to the textview?

Comment: @wazzar Sure, you can get it to display as you wish.  I'd put it in a ViewModel, so that it survives device rotations.   When appending it, you can also use append("\n") to add line breaks.  Have fun, Android development is quite an adventure.

Comment: Can't seem to make it work.. Still looking for the problem though. Will try to log

Comment: @Ewald i tried logging the value of startPos and endPos, it returns 0, and -1. I used your code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok if I got you right, I hope I did, this should do the trick:

```
// Code begins with a splitted array so String[] list exists already
int address = 0; // this will determine where your Address is located in the array
int license = -1; // this will determine where license is located in the array

for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].equals("Address"))
        address = i;
    else if (address != 0 && list[i].equals("License")) {
        license = i;
        break;    // loop can be left as everything else is unimportant
    }
}

String[] result = new String[license-address-1]; // This will throw an error on purpose if license and/or address were not in list
for (int i = address+1; i < license; i++)
    result[i-address-1] = list[i]; // actual copying
// Be happy with your result String[]
```

Comment: Ah, the pro answer!  Nice - I really like the optimisations here.

Comment: Really helpful! Tried using your code, but I'm having a problem. It grabs the string starting after Address, but it doesnt stop before "License". How do I fix this?

Comment: Sorry! My bad. Forgot to put in the break in the loop. Works perfectly now. Thanks to you and @Ewald for helping a beginner out! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @wazzar, I missed this due to the timezones.  Awesome stuff for pushing through, that's what development is all about.